# Adding a descriptor to a Python subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, descriptor, python-descriptors

I have a python class that inherits a priority queue and I also use a descriptor to add an attribute to the class, like this:

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
class My_Class(PriorityQueue):
    my_attr = NonNegativeInt(0)

    def __init__(self):
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self)
```

The descriptor is implemented like this:

```
class NonNegativeInt(object):
  def __init__(self, default):
      self.default = default
      self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()

  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
      return self.data.get(instance, self.default)

  def __set__(self, instance, value):

      if type(value) is not int:
          raise TypeError('Value must be an int')

      if value < 0:
          raise ValueError("Value must be above 0")

       self.data[instance] = value
```

When I call `My_Class.my_attr = -1` I don't get any exception.  However, if I change `My_Class` to this I get the exception fine:

```
class My_Class(object):
    my_attr = NonNegativeInt(0)

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Interestingly, the first implementation of `My_Class` starts with the `my_attr` attribute, it just doesn't execute the `__set__` function in `NonNegativeInt`.

Why is it that changing the superclass changes how my descriptor works?  Does it have to do with this line: `PriorityQueue.__init__(self)`?  How can I give the subclass the behavior I want?

Comment: You mean you inherit from `object` (lowercase), and you are setting the attribute on an *instance* of `My_Class`, right?

Comment: And where does `PriorityQueue` come from?

Comment: Yes, I inherit from `object`, that was just a typo.

Comment: PriorityQueue comes from Queue, another typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptors only work on *new-style classes* (those that directly or indirectly inherit from `object`). There is some support for descriptor `__get__` methods on old-style classes but this support is limited.

The `PriorityQueue` class you are using probably doesn't inherit from `object`. If this is the [`Queue.PriorityQueue` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue) then that's certainly the case, the classes in that module are all old-style.

The fact that you call `PriorityQueue.__init__` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: If I change `My_Class` to this, it seems to work: `class My_Class(PriorityQueue, object):`.  Is there any reason I should avoid that?

Comment: @devin: If you were to use `super()` to get to overridden methods, or to use multiple inheritance (past mixing in `object`) there might well be issues, but for your usecase I **think** that should be fine.